# GAE (Python) Defining entity relationships in ndb

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

How would you go about creating a relationship between two different entity models?

When I try this I get an error:

```
class Spec(ndb.Model):
    userKey = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=User)

class User(ndb.Model):
    specs = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Spec, repeated=True)
```

The error as I understand stems from referencing User before it is defined.
I did the following to solve it, and I use a get_by_id, but I do not like this solution:

```
class Spec(ndb.Model):
    userKey = ndb.IntegerProperty()

class User(ndb.Model):
    specs = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Spec, repeated=True)
```

How would you solve this so I can define my models as in the first example? Even better, how would you go about to define each class in its own file/module.

I tried following this article, but it seems to be be outdated and not relevant to ndb.
https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/modeling

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As [the docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/properties) show, the `kind` argument can be a string. So use `kind='User'`.